# replacing column value based in a line containing a specific string

Tags: text, awk

I have text file :

```
file_11199_name  45  69
file_11176_name  45  69
file_11156_name  45  69
```

where i want change the value of column three to 1 when the first column has "11199" in the string.

Comment: Welcome to SO, on SO we encourage users to show their efforts which they have put in order to solve their own problem so kindly add your efforts in your question and let us know then.

Answer (score 0):

the next, 3-lines, of AWK code seems to do what you need:

```
{c=$3}
$1~11199{c=1}
{ print $1,$2,c }
```

line 1 assigns a variable (c) with the value of the third column.
line 2 assigns the value 1 to `c` if the first variable contains 11199 (`$1~11199`)
line 3 prints the output

```
$ awk '{c=$3}$1~11199{c=1}{ print $1,$2,c }' file
file_11199_name 45 1
file_11176_name 45 69
file_11156_name 45 69
```